# magento nginx redirection for migration

Tags: magento, configuration, nginx

I have 2 website. Let's say website A and B.
Both are using Magento.

Almost all of products in B also built-in in A.

Website B is going to be closed hence all of its matching products will be redirected to website A.
For other page (non-matching products & other url) will be redirected to A's homepage.

I created script to map matching products from B to A (put it under name mapping.txt), it contains around 20000 url.

To do the redirection, I'm using nginx HttpMapModule (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule)

I was able to map it by using this conf:

```
map $uri $new{
    default http://www.a.com/?ref=b;
    include /some/path/mapping.txt;
}

server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.b.com;
    root /some/path/www/b;

    #redirect b
    rewrite ^ $new redirect;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The problem is, I want to be able to access B's admin page.
Because of the default map, I can not access `http://www.b.com/admin` anymore.

Then, I changed the conf:

```
map $uri $new{
    default http://www.a.com/?ref=b;
    include /some/path/mapping.txt;
}

server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.b.com;
    root /some/path/www/b;

    location / {
        #redirect b
        rewrite ^ $new redirect;
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

By this conf, I still unable to access `http://www.b.com/admin` but I can access `http://www.b.com/index.php/admin` but the css and js are not loaded because request to (`http://www.b.com/skin/.....` and `http://www.b.com/js/.....` are redirected to `http://www.a.com/?ref=b`)

But this conf is also problematic, it won't redirect to A's homepage if I type `http://www.b.com/index.php/customer/account/login`

example content of mapping.txt:

```
/product-abc.html http://www.a.com/product-abc12.html;
/category-a/product-xyz.html http://www.a.com/product-xyz.html;
/category-b/category-d/product-123.html http://www.a.com/category-e/product-12z.html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple domain redirect on .htaccess for these generic cases...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.a.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.b.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```